# Cannot insert decimal from textbox into database

Tags: asp.net, sql, web

I am struggling with getting my sql database to accept a decimal from a textbox on my website page. When I enter a whole number there is no issue, it is only when I enter a decimal (123.45) that I get the issue. I have tried `double.parse(textbox.text)` and `decimal.parse(textbox.text)` to no avail.

I get the error message

> input string was not in the correct format

My insert statement is below:

```
"INSERT INTO Transactions (Date, Account, Payee, Chq_Num, Reference, GST_Rate, 
 Amount, Document_Number, Bank_Account) VALUES ('" & yy & "-" & mm & "-" & dd & 
 "','" & DropDownList3.SelectedValue & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & 
 TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "'," & DropDownList2.SelectedValue & 
 "," & Double.Parse(TextBox6.Text) & "," & TextBox27.Text & ",'" &  
 DropDownList1.SelectedValue & "'); INSERT INTO Cash (Date, Bank_Account, 
 Amount, Document_Number) VALUES ('" & yy & "-" & mm & "-" & dd & "','" & 
 DropDownList1.SelectedValue & "'," & Double.Parse(TextBox2.Text) & "," & 
 TextBox27.Text & ");"
```

My database field is set to decimal(18,2) Any ideas?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Not to be petty but really for your own sanity you should probably also name the text boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is telling that input string was not in the correct format. Means that you are trying to convert wrong value to decimal.

Put a try/catch around the code to see what is being passed in to ParseDouble. This should help determine what is causing the problem  and that should help determine where it is coming from. Is a user entering it in a textbox?

Please try "double.TryParse"  in place of "Double.Parse".

```
double temp = 0;
if (double.TryParse("123.456", out temp)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Parsed temp: {0}", temp);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input value was not able to be parsed.");
}
```

Comment: Turns out it was not the textbox itself but another validation i was making that was wrong, thanks for your help Sain Pradeep, pointed me in the right direction